# Can you query a backup device?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, database-backups

I would like to get information from a backup of a server (SQL 2008 R2). Do I have to restore the database backup to do this? Is there any way to query the backup?

Comment: you cannot query `.bak` files. You need to restore

Comment: Yes you have to restore the backup before you can query it.

Comment: Why would someone down-vote this? You shouldn't be allowed to down-vote without a reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't query your backup files. You can always restore the database using the WITH REPLACE option to restore it under a different name.

Let's say you have a production DB and you want to restore it as a test database.

You can use WITH REPLACE option to restore TestDB from a .bak file containing a ProductionDB. I also use WITH MOVE option to replace the .mdf and .ldf files:

```
USE [master]

RESTORE DATABASE [TestDB] FROM  DISK = N'C:\ProductionDB.bak' 
WITH MOVE N'ProductionDB' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\TestDB.mdf',  
MOVE N'ProductionDB_log' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\TestDB_log.ldf', 
REPLACE

GO
```

Comment: Give an example of WITH REPLACE usage and you get best answer.

Comment: @KthProg I just added an example.